# Debugger jumps from one line to another (out of order) inside a loop. What is wrong?

Tags: c#, debugging, loops

I have a `for` loop that reads lines from an Excel file, checks them and inserts the data into an SQL database using LINQ.

The strange thing is that when I debug the program, it doesn't seem to run in the order of the code, it just jumps from one line to any other line, then and back to a previous line of code.

I can't debug like that. It's strange and I am afraid that this behaviour might affect the final results.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it jump from the end of the `for` block back to the beginning of the `for` block?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: This is a symptom of debugging multi-threaded code. Is this the case? Are you using parallel for or multiple threds?

Comment: I cannot remember a specific code example, but I have seen LINQ queries cause this kind of behaviour. Because LINQ queries are evaluated lazily by default -- i.e. as long as you don't do things like sorting, or calling `.ToList()` -- the debugger *might* jump back to a LINQ query expression whenever you pull an element from the sequence defined by that expression.

Comment: Btw., it might also help if you mentioned what debugger you are using (Visual Studio? If so, which version?) and *how* you debug this program. Are you stepping through the code line-by-line? Have you tried setting breakpoints on every line? Have you tried setting a breakpoint only at the loop's very beginning, and then counted how many times the loop is run (and compared that to the number of lines in your Excel file)? etc.

Comment: Are you debugging in release mode? Compiler optimization can show odd behavior during debugging (at least in c++ perhaps the same is happening in c#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the code being executed is not the same as the one you see in the debugger. Try to rebuild your solution to ensure the most current version is being executed.

Comment: I did it before, Its something about Diffrent Thread, and i didn't execute any diffrent Thread...

Comment: @ItayM: is the code being invoked from some event (e.g. a timer)?

Comment: Nope, Just Regullar loop, big one (about 13K rows) but "for" loop.